# InstantiationException after migrating from Butterknife to Android's Viewbinding

Tags: java, android, butterknife, android-viewbinding

I have an Android Project using Java and Butterknife for view binding. I am in the process of migrating to Androids viewbinding. I made all the necessary changes but I am faced with this error when trying to test out the new app after migration:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity
> ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.ui.splash.SplashActivity}:
> java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.example.ui.splash.SplashActivity> has no zero
> argument constructor

> Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
> java.lang.Class<com.example.ui.splash.SplashActivity> has no zero
> argument constructor

I can't make sense of this error. Heres my `SplashActivity` class:

```
public class SplashActivity extends BaseActivity<ActivitySplashBinding> {

    public SplashActivity(ActivitySplashBinding binding) {
        super(binding);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And here is the `BaseActivity` class:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity<VB extends ViewBinding> extends AppCompatActivity {

    protected VB binding;

    public BaseActivity(VB binding) {
        this.binding = binding;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AndroidInjection.inject(this);
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());
    }
}
```

What am I missing here ?